# PrototypeJS breaking SpahQL results

Tags: json, prototypejs

I'm having a hard time trying to use the SpahQL to query JSON in parallel with PrototypeJS.
The weird behavior is when I create a new instance of the SpahQL, the newly created object comes with several functions attached to it, but not by default, its attached by PrototypeJS.
Whatever a call select or any other method from SpahQL, those functions are interpreted as result objects and then added to the result set.

A simple example to explain my point:

```
`<script src="path/to/spahql-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
`<script src="path/to/data.json" type="text/javascript"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript">`
`var db = SpahQL.db(data);`
`sample = db.select("/*/*");`
`console.log(sample);`
```

Supose that data.json contains 50 entries, so the console.log will show an array of 50 objects.
But I include the PrototypeJS to the snippet the console.log will output an array of 1558 objects:

```
`<script src="path/to/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
`<script src="path/to/spahql-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
`<script src="path/to/data.json" type="text/javascript"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript">`
`var db = SpahQL.db(data);`
`sample = db.select("/*/*");`
`console.log(sample);`
```